# Outputting a byte arrain into the src attribute of an img tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and have a model which has an image (byte array) in one of the fields. I'm trying to output this image into the src attribute of the img tag. I'm looking to do something like `<img src='<%= Model.VenueImage  %>'>`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Maybe [Inline Images with Data URLs](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/) idea?

> Inline images use the data URI scheme
>   to embed images directly within web
>   pages. As defined by RFC 2397, data
>   URIs are designed to embed small data
>   items as "immediate" data, as if they
>   were referenced externally. Using
>   inline images saves HTTP requests over
>   externally referenced objects.

```
System.Drawing.Image image = GetImageFromSomewhere(...);

byte[] imageData = ImageToByteArray(image);
string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imageData);
string imageSrc = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", imageBase64);
```

and then somewhere in the page:

```
<img src= "<%= ImageSrcBytes %>" />
```

AFAIK this will work for Opera 7.2+, Firefox, Safari, Netscape, Mozilla and IE8+ (IE8 up to 32kb).

For earlier version of IE there is a workaround - [MHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mhtml).

The example how to do it is [here](http://www.phpied.com/data-uris-mhtml-ie7-win7-vista-blues/).

Comment: This does not seem to work in internet explorer 7/8, any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

The browser uses the src attribute to issue a separate request to the server, to get the contents of the image. It does not display the bytes in the src as the image itself.

So you will need to remember those bytes (session?) and use a handler (the url you put into the src attribute) to let the browser request them.