# Consequences of inline images

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

One part of my application requires a bunch of images (representing scale) on screen. Because of the wide variety of possibilities, I'd rather generate the images programmatically than pre-create and store all possible images (some of which may never be used). This seems doable using the methed described in [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644542/outputting-a-byte-arrain-into-the-src-attribute-of-an-img-tag/2644598#2644598).

However, the two pages which will use these images will have plenty of them (potentially a couple hundred on one of the pages). My question, then, is will this negatively impact the performance of the application, and if so, how drastically? The pages could potentially be reloaded several times as values change.

Would it be best to generate the images when the page is loaded? Best to precreate them and store several hundred, possibly only using a few? Or would it be best to programmatically create them the first time they are loaded, and then store them under the assumption that since they have been used once, they will likely be used again (assuming they would still be valid - it is quite possible for them to become invalid and need to be replaced)?

**EDIT**: Each of these images represents a number, which is an application-wide variable. It is expected that most of these numbers will be different, although there may be some few that are equal.

Comment: Are the images unique per user, or global per application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not do both, programatically generate images as needed but cache them (i.e. save them as files on the server) so they can be reused.

Further to your edit: If the images are simple image representations of numbers then just pregenerate 0 to 9 and then programatically glue them together at runtime.

Comment: I have considered that, but once used, there is no guarantee that an image will be used again.

Comment: Why is that a problem?  Are you short of disc space on the server? It will still take less space the pre-generating all images unless all images are used at some point. If you are worried about stale images you could have some kind of cache cleanup that kept the space used to a given level and deleted least frequently used images first.

Comment: @Jim: That's why well-designed caches (like the ones in .NET) automatically "forget" their old contents after a period of time.

Comment: They aren't representations of numbers in that sense, they are essentially meters that must fill to a point to represent a number. However, the value where a meter would be "full" is subject to change during use.

Comment: It all comes down to the range of different values you need to represent and the distribution of likely values across the range.  What you need to work out is "how often will i get the same number twice in x amount of time", if that number is high then caching is worth the disk space, if that number is low then it is not.