# Show image using binary array and the FancyBox plugin(jQuery)

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I need some help or information with showing the image int the `<img>` tag when the `src` attribute is the binary array (ASP.NET MVC 3):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2644598/106616

this I the solution I use. **(the purpose is, i don't want to show users the physical image path)**

Ok, then I want to use the [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/) plugin to show that image:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <a id="book-cover-hl" href="@path">
    <img alt='' class='book-cover-details' src="@path" />
  </a>

  $(function () {
         $("a#book-cover-hl").fancybox({
             'overlayShow': false,
             'transitionIn': 'elastic',
             'transitionOut': 'elastic'
         });
   });
```

> But, I've noticed if I put the `@path` variable in the `<a [...]
>   href="@path">` the plugin doesn't work properly - if I click on the
>   image, only the loading animation shows, but not my image. Does anyone
>   know how to fix it? Or maybe there is another idea ? Let me hear it
>   from You about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [that](http://osdir.com/ml/fancybox/2011-07/msg00349.html) answer, it works:

> If you want to use fancybox with data uri images like.
>
> ```
> <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD//
> gA8Q1JFQVRPUjogZ2QtanBlZyB2MS4wICh1c2luZyBJSkcgSlBFRyB2NzApLCBxdWFsaXR5ID0gMTAwCv/
> bAEMAAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB......
> ```
>
> you need to change somethings in jquery fancybox script.
>
> 1) Base on Version: 1.3.4 (11/11/2010) 2) Change line 23 for this one.
>
> ajaxLoader = null, imgPreloader = new Image(), imgRegExpdatauri=/
>   (data:image)/i ,imgRegExp = /.(jpg|gif|png|bmp|jpeg)(.*)?$/i,
>   swfRegExp = /[^.].(swf)\s*$/i,
>
> 3) change lines 113-117 for this ones
>
> if (href.match(imgRegExpdatauri)) { type = 'image2';
>
> } else if (href.match(imgRegExp)) { type = 'image';
>
> 4) Insert this lines after break; on line 197
>
> case 'image2': busy = false;
>
> $.fancybox.showActivity();
>
> imgPreloader = new Image();
>
> imgPreloader.onerror = function() {
>   _error(); };
>
> imgPreloader.onload = function() { busy = true;
>
> imgPreloader.onerror = imgPreloader.onload = null;
>
> _process_image(); };
>
> imgPreloader.src = href; break;
>
> Now it should work.

Comment: On number 1, there's an extra space in the regexp. It should be: `ajaxLoader = null, imgPreloader = new Image(), imgRegExpdatauri=/(data:image)/i ,imgRegExp = /.(jpg|gif|png|bmp|jpeg)(.)?$/i, swfRegExp = /[^.].(swf)\s$/i,`