# Display Bitmap in model with Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

A webApp I am currently working on requires me to store photos as a `byte[]` in the database.  It then needs me to pull those out and display them in a view.  I created a `photoContainer` which holds the bitmap instead of the `byte[]` and pass that to the view.  But I can't seem to figure out how to display it from there.  I've tried setting the source to the `model.Image` and that didn't work.  Is there anyway to display a bitmap in my model in the view?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In a controller place this

```
public FileResult GetImg(int id)
    {                       
         var image = db.Categories.First(m => m.CategoryID == id).Picture;

         byte[] imageData;
         if(image != null)
         {
             imageData = image.ToArray();
             return File( imageData, image.contentType );
         }
         else
         {
             return null;
         }
     }
```

In your view place this

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetImg", "ControllerTheActionAboveIsPlacedIn", new { id = Model.ImageId})" />
```

Comment: This solution requires that a new db call be made for each image.  The model at the view level already contains the byte[].  Isn't there a more efficient way of rendering the image at that point without going back to the db for each image?

Comment: You can use this approach but it doesn't work in IE7 and below.  IE8 is limited also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644542/outputting-a-byte-arrain-into-the-src-attribute-of-an-img-tag/2644598#2644598